# how can I convert .swf file to HTML file?

Tags: html, flash

I am looking for ways to convert .swf file to html5 file. I reviewed other similar questions and unfortunately, they have outdated solutions.

Comment: .sfw files need flash to work. HTML5 has nothing to do with flash.

Comment: I googled **swf to html** and there's quite a lot, including some conversion tools. Please elaborate why none of them suits you so you had to resort to StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't just convert it.  It's an entirely different featureset, different language, etc.

You need to re-develop whatever it was you had in your SWF to begin with.